# Problema com Algorítimo de Pilha

Tags: c#, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Comecei a programar em C# recentemente e já estou com alguns problemas... Peguei um exercício do URI para treinar e estou com um "erro" que não sei como resolver.Já procurei vários lugares e não achei nada. Enfim, vamos a situação:

O algoritmo resolve balanceamento de parênteses dada uma entrada qualquer. Utilizei uma leitura de arquivos com o BufferedStream para pegar as linhas com as quais desejo trabalhar. Porém ao rodar com umas 20 entradas no txt o negócio não sai como esperado. As entradas como **)** e **()()** dão erro(ou seja, não saem o resultado correto). Não sei se existe algum esquema específico na leitura do arquivo pois como disse estou iniciando na linguagem.

Segue o código:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Stack<char> elements = new Stack<char>();
    string input;
    FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath,FileMode.Open);
    BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs);
    while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (c.Equals('(')) elements.Push(c);
            if (c.Equals(')'))
            {
                if (elements.Count != 0) elements.Pop();
                else elements.Push(c);
            }
        }
        if (elements.Count == 0) Console.WriteLine("correct "+ input);
        else Console.WriteLine("incorrect "+ input);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

*Tirei o filepath só pra não mostrar meu diretório, mas ele existe! 
Segue uma entrada exemplo:

```
(
)
()
)(
()(
())
(()
)()
()()
())(
)(()
(())
))((
)()(
)(()
(()())
```

O mais interessante é que se ao rodar com o txt com uma única entrada,por exemplo, apenas **)**, o resultado sai correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa limpar a pilha,  `elements.Clear()`, depois de analisar cada linha.

```
while ((input = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...

    elements.Clear();
}
```